# Can XWS be used to authenticate REST API using Node JS?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I need to implement REST Server using Node JS. I'm using JWT for Authentication but requirements ask me to implement custom HMAC authentication named XWS. Reading Oracle Doc I see that XWS is used to SOAP.
Is possible to use XWS and Node JS?
Is JWT the best solution to autheticate REST API using Node?
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a link to the doc you reference?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/XWS-SecurityIntro4.html

Comment: "The XWS-Security framework is used to secure JAX-RPC and stand-alone SAAJ applications." Do the requirements know you're writing an application in Node.js and not Java? I see there's an HMAC strategy for Passport here: http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-hmac/ Would that work?